# Use field calculator in QGIS so get number of points in polygone and store it in attribute table

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, point-in-polygon

I have to layers, one point one polygon (with 6 areas) stored as shapefiles.
Now I want to count the number of points in each area and write it into the attribute table of the polygons. A column sum_poi already exists.

Can I use the field calculator to populate the column in the polygon layer?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not that easy. You have to use `Vector -> Analysis Tools -> Points in Polygons`.

That will create a new layer with an additional attribute column with the numer of points inside each polygon.

See this tutorial for assistance:

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/points_in_polygon.html

Comment: Thanks. But this solution creates a completely new layer. There is no possibility to write it into the existing shapefile?

Comment: You can remove the old layer, then `Save As ...` the new one to the name of the original shapefile.